# Scrapy scraped only the 4 pages

Tags: python, scrapy

this is scraped only the 4 links and returned 15 scraped item/row but i need to scrape 20 links with 35+ scraped item.

If you anyone help me that's would be very helpful for me

ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class TastySpider(Spider):
    name = 'tasty'
    allowed_domains = ['tasty.co']
    start_urls = ['https://tasty.co/topic/game-day']


    def parse(self, response):
        lists=response.css('a.feed-item::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in lists:
            link=response.urljoin(link)
            if link:
                yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_page)


    def parse_page(self, response):
        Recipe_URL=response.url
        Title=response.xpath('//h1//text()').extract_first()
        instruction=response.css('ol.prep-steps li.xs-mb2::text').extract()
        Cooking_time=response.xpath('//*[@class="recipe-time-container xs-flex xs-mx2 xs-relative xs-b0 md-b2 xs-mt2 md-mt0"]//p//text()').extract_first()
        Image_video_URL=response.xpath('//*[@property="og:image"]//@content').extract_first()
        servings=response.xpath('//h2[contains(text(),"Ingredients")]//following-sibling::p//text()').extract_first()

        Us_measurement=response.xpath('//*[@class="measurement us-measurement xs-inline-block"]//text()').extract()

        Ingredient=response.xpath('//*[@class="xs-mb1 xs-mt0"]//section//following-sibling::text()').extract()

        Non_us_measurement=response.xpath('//*[@class="measurement non-us-measurement xs-inline-block"]//text()').extract()


        for Us_measur, Ingred, Non_us in zip(Us_measurement, Ingredient, Non_us_measurement):
            Us_measur=Us_measur.strip()

            Ingred=Ingred.strip()

            Non_us=Non_us.strip()


            yield {
                    'Us-measurement':Us_measur,
                    'Ingredient':Ingred,
                    'Non-us-measurement':Non_us,
                    'Recipe_URL':Recipe_URL,
                    'Title':Title,
                    'instruction':instruction,
                    'Cooking_time':Cooking_time,
                    'Servings':servings,
                    'Image-video_URL':Image_video_URL


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy does actually crawl the 20 links you wish to scrape.

However, only the `/recipe/` links contain the data you're trying to scrape.
The `/compilation/` links only contain links to other recipes.

The simplest way to approach this would probably be using a [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider), and creating separate rules for recipe and compilation links.